# Is it possible to query a search engine through Matlab?

Tags: matlab, yahoo

I was wondering if it is possible to query a search engine via matlab. I would like to get the amount of hits for a certain query via matlab.

Comment: See [this post](http://blog.xkcd.com/2011/02/04/trochee-chart/) about caution you should have interpreting the number of hits returned by, at least, google. Apparently they are very bad guesses and absolutely no good for measurements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
S = urlread('https://www.google.com/search?q=test');
```

This will return the HTML spat out by Google when querying it with the keyword "test". You can then do something like

```
% search engine specific filter for no. of results
results = regexpi(S, 'About [0-9_\,]* results', 'match'); 

% parse further or error out
if ~isempty(results)    
    results = textscan(results{1}, '%s'); % tokenize string
    results = str2double(results{2}); % number of results
else
    error('Something went wrong during the query.');
end
```

Note that `urlread` requires Java running, so obviously you can't do it when running with the `-nojvm` startup option (my first attempt :)

Comment: Thx for the answer. Though still one problem. S consists of the html. But results is empty. I changed your url to google.com. And nothing changed. In the html it looks like this "About 2,940,000,000 results". But this:  regexpi(S,'About \d* results') does not work.

Comment: See my edit for the correct `regexp` expression. As for why the urlread fails -- have you tried some other search engine?

Comment: The urlreads works, your regexp works too (it gives something back, which is not equal to the number of hits). The error I get now is on the textscan. The error:Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Comment: @Ojtwist: Yes, stupid of me. `regexp` returns the index to where the match occurs. You need to specify you want to return the match(es); see my edit.